# Change Cell Value with DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a problem to edit a cell in a `datagridview` which is connected to a database in c#

I am using this code `dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[5].Value = 20;` i would like to change the value of the first row and cell 6 (column 6) but i get a runtime error saying that my index is out of bounds.

How can I edit a value directly?

Comment: how are you populating your dataGridView ??? Obviously you don't have six columns

Comment: I do have six columns and i am populating it from the database, thus when i change values directly from the database i see them but i cannot programatically change them

Comment: So provide your code and we will see how are you populating it,how can we help you without seeing any code??

Comment: The problem is that i do not have any code i just dragged the DGV and connected it with a wizard than trying to access a single cell as i explained before

Comment: when you are trying to change your value,after populate your dgv or before?

Comment: Ihave tried after and before it is still the same error

Comment: I can't say anything more unless I see the relevant code

Comment: try `dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[4].Value = 20;` if you get same error then try with index = 3 and so on...